# Firebase function to get data within a document returns Promise pending

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know this code is probably awful, but I'm trying to get data from my Firebase database and everything works but the function within the for loop always returns Promise {pending}, and I'm not sure what to do to fix that.

```
for(var i = 0; i < querySnapshot.size; i++){
        var blah = firestore.collection("testList").doc(i.toString());
        lines[i] = blah.get().then(function(doc){
            return doc.data().text;
        });
        console.log(lines[i]);
    }
    var finalText = lines.join("\n");
```

Comment: then() always returns another promise.  It doesn't immediately return what its callback function returns.  The returned promise resolves to the value returned by the function, whenever it completes.  You might want to read up on how promises work because this comes up a lot in JavaScript.

Comment: check out [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) used in conjunction with  [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait for all documents to be loaded, you're looking for `Promise.all()`:

```
const promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < querySnapshot.size; i++){
    var blah = firestore.collection("testList").doc(i.toString());
    promises.push(blah.get().then();
}
Promise.all(promises).then(function(docs){
    return docs.map(function(doc)
        return doc.data().text;
    });
}).then(function(lines) {
    var finalText = lines.join("\n");
    console.log(finalText);
});
```

You might want to read up on asynchronous code and promises, as this is quite common and you'll keep bumping into learning problems until you grok these concepts.

Some good starting points:

- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)
- [Learn JavaScript Promises (Pt.1) with HTTP Triggers in Cloud Functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA)
- [Graceful asynchronous programming with Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises)